# Empty token default values -- core or extension support?

Tags: tokens

I want to provide a default value for tokens when the value is empty, on a per-use basis -- e.g., something like `{contact.first_name?Friend}` would print the contact's First Name if it's not empty, otherwise print "Friend".

**Rationale update:** This would allow non-programmers to easily specify a default value without needing to clutter up the tokens UI.

Existing workarounds for this functionality are more cumbersome than that:

- [Dave's blog from version 2.2](https://civicrm.org/blog/dave-greenberg/civimail-how-to-add-default-values-for-empty-tokens) uses hooks in an extension to hard-code defaults for specific tokens in all cases.
- [This SE answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/23088/907) points out that this can be achieved by enabling Smarty processing and then inserting a few lines -- per token -- of Smarty code into the content.

To avoid double-work and/or undertaking the impossible, I ask:

Has any attempt been made to put such per-use-default-value functionality into CiviCRM core or an extension?

**Technical challenges update:** Tokens are limited to `\w` characters, so any plan to use a non-word delimiter like `?` will have to involve changes in core, as far as I can see.

Comment: I think the Smarty solution is simple enough. If you want it be on a per-use basis, I don't see how you can do it elsewhere without adding significant functionality to tokens.

Comment: I do like your proposal.

Answer (score 3):

First - no need to enable Smarty system-wide to do this.  Greetings are always parsed by Smarty - see https://civicrm.org/blog/antrik/getting-started-with-new-name-and-greetings-features-in-45.

Besides that, I think you're one of the leading experts on complex token extensions, since you're the primary author of [reltoken](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.reltoken).  But I don't see why you couldn't do this.  `hook_civicrm_tokenValues` gives you access to the token name for parsing, and there's no requirement that the token be listed with `hook_civicrm_tokens`.  So I'd say go for it.

Note that this is similar but not identical to the free-form relative date work Eileen did: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12682.

Comment: Tokens are limited to [\w] characters, so any plan to use a non-word delimiter like `?` will have to involve changes in core. I'm concerned that will mushroom into something more than I want to undertake.